# does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

Tags: python, django

I got

> does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import  error .

I wrote in urls.py of child app

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.views import login,logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout')
]
```

in urls.py of parent app,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('UserToken.urls')),
    url(r'^UserDataAPI/', include('UserDataAPI.urls', namespace='UserDataAPI')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am thinking urls.py of child or parent app,but I do not know how to fix it.
What should I do?

Comment: Which is the child app? accounts?

Comment: How can you do `from django.contrib.views import login,logout` ? Also default `login` and `logout` you cannot use it as a view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import is incorrect. The `views.py` containing `login` and `logout` is in the `django.contrib.auth` app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
```

Answer (score 2):

just check whether urlpattern and change into patterns

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by errors in views.py file as code code redirect link isn't properly working.
so,Check views file to remove error

Answer (score 0):

In your outermost urls file, if you are including other package urls like

`path("accounts/", include("UserDataAPI.urls"))`

or

`url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))`

Ensure that in `accounts.urls` module or `UserDataAPI.urls` modules you have declared the `urlpatterns` variable